# Router preventing access to the rest of the network

Tags: router, network-shares, dd-wrt

I'm on a network where we share a media server between all residents. If I connect my laptop directly to the network it detects the media server (through samba) without issues.

Recently I've added a router to my own network to be able to also connect my desktop as well. The problem is that now I've lost access to the network on which the media server resides (probably since I'm on a different subnet now). So my laptop and desktop can't detect the media server any longer. All I now see is the desktop and the laptop itself.

How do I make my router a "transparent" part of the network, so I can once again find the media server? My router is running DD-WRT by the way.

Comment: How does your router connect to the existing network exactly? Do you have a single wired port?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, there's one cable connected to the WAN-port of my router, which gives (or should give) me access to the www and the media server-network. My laptop and desktop are connected to the switch ports on this router (so the LAN ports I guess you'd call it?).

Comment: Yeah, see my answer. You shouldn't be connecting your router's WAN port to your LAN. (Unless you configure the router to use the WAN port as just another LAN port, which I presume you haven't done.) Make sure to disable the DHCP server in your router -- two on one LAN will make big trouble.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, I tried that, but the problem is that the cable that connects me to the buildings LAN also connects me to the www. If I put it in a regular router LAN port, I gain access to the network, but lose my internet connection.

Comment: So troubleshoot to figure out the problem. Did you disable the DHCP server? Did you release/renew your DHCP lease (or reboot)?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, well the problem is I also need to clone my mac address for internet access (and my router used to do that). If I don't use the wan-port, I need to clone the mac-address locally on my machines, but that would mean that I'm using the network with two identical mac-adresses, which will cause conflicts. Is there any way to solve that, that you know of? Could I possibly use some sort of NAT?

Comment: Oh, boy, you have a much more complex issue than you let on.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, I'm sorry, I guess I should have explained it better. It's just that it's not something I understand very well myself.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, what if I split the outgoing network cable (with a switch or something), and plug one part in the WAN port for www-access (and clone the mac-adress for outgoing www-traffic with the router), and put one in a LAN-port for network access (for which a cloned mac-address isn't neccesary)?

Comment: Then you'll have web access but not Internet access. You should talk to whoever manages this network. Ask them how it's supposed to work.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, Yeah I've tried that. Unfortunately they tried, failed, and then told me I was on my own..

Answer (score 0):

1. You obviously have to configure the WAN port of your router to the MAC address which your Internet gateway expects. I have no idea whether DD-WRT offers that. Could be done with OpenWRT.
2. Your router must masquerade your connections (NAT).
3. Depending on the configuration of the network you either have to set the IP address for the router's WAN interface of activate a DHCP client on that interface.
4. It should be easiest to use DHCP on the LAN ports, too.